# What are the equivalents of AppBar parameters (material-ui version 0.20 ) in version 3.9.3 of mui?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui, migration

I have a website based on mui 0.20 & i want to upgrade it. For example, I want to migrate the AppBar of version 0.20 to version 3.9.3, the properties are:

- iconElementLeft
- iconElementRight
- onLeftIconButtonClick
- showMenuIconButton
- zDepth ....

I can't find the equivalents for these parameters in version 3.9.3, i face the same situation for the other components, is there a way to migrate ?